# Three-dimensional array as a vector of arrays

Tags: c++

I have 3-dim double array with two of its dimensions known at compile time.
So to make it efficient, I'd like to write something like

```
std::vector<double[7][19]> v;
v.resize(3);
v[2][6][18] = 2 * 7*19 + 6 * 19 + 18;
```

It's perfect except it does not compile because of "v.resize(3);"
Please don't recommend me using nested vectors like

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> v;
```

because I don't want to set sizes for known dimensions each time I extend v by its first dimension.

What is the cleanest solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of `std::array` of `double`?

```
std::vector<std::array<std::array<double, 19>, 7>> v;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of when it's both reasonable and useful to inherit from `std::vector`, providing:

- you can be sure they won't be deleted using a pointer to their vector base class (which would be Undefined Behaviour as the `vector` destructor's not `virtual`)
- you're prepared to write a forwarding constructor or two if you want to use them
- ideally, you're using this in a relatively small application rather than making it part of a library API with lots of distributed client users - the more hassle client impact could be, the more pedantic one should be about full encapsulation

```
template <typename T, size_t Y, size_t Z>
struct Vec_3D : std::vector<std::array<std::array<T, Y>, Z>>
{
    T& operator(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
    {
        return (*this)[x * Y * Z + y * Y + z];
    }

    const T& operator(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) const
    {
        return (*this)[x * Y * Z + y * Y + z];
    }
};
```

So little effort, then you've got a nicer and less error prone `v(a, b, c)` notation available.

Concerning the derivation, note that:

- your derived type makes no attempt to enforce different invariants on the object
- it doesn't add any data members or other bases

(The lack of data members / extra bases means even slicing and accidental deletion via a `vector*` are likely to work in practice, even though they should be avoided it's kind of nice to know you're likely playing with smoke rather than fire.)

Yes I know Alexandrescu, Sutter, Meyers etc. recommend not to do this - I've read their reasons very carefully several times and if you want to champion them even for this usage, please bring relevant technical specifics to the table....